# lodash generate deep object with collection data

Tags: javascript, database, lodash

Hi suppose i have access to those data ref

```js
const GlobalDataA = { uid0: {}, uid1: {}, uid2: {} };
const GlobalDataB = { uid3: {}, uid4: {}, uid5: {} }; 

const mapperA = ['uid0', 'uid1'];
const mapperB = ['uid3', 'uid4'];

const range = 4;
```

how i can easily with Lodash generate a new collections object with keys uid like this

```js
{
    uid0: { uid3: [0, 1, 2, 3], uid4: [0, 1, 2, 3] },
    uid1: { uid3: [0, 1, 2, 3], uid4: [0, 1, 2, 3] },
}
```

---

i know how proceed to generate a collections array

```js
const test = mapperA.map((A) => mapperB.map((B) => _.range(range).map((value, i) => i)));
```

it will give me this

[image]

but my target is to generate a new object with uid key like this

[image]

ideally a 1 or 2 line formula to stay clean will be great !
I try pick and zipObject from loadash without success !
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return pairs of [key, value] from the `_.map()` calls, and convert to objects using `_.fromPairs()`:

```js
const mapperA = ['uid0', 'uid1'];
const mapperB = ['uid3', 'uid4'];

const range = 4;

const result = _.fromPairs(mapperA.map((A) => 
  [
    A, 
    _.fromPairs(mapperB.map((B) => [
      B,
      _.range(range)
    ]))
  ])
);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

With vanilla JS, you can replace `_.fromPairs()` with `Object.fromEntries()`, and generate the range with `Array.from()`:

```js
const mapperA = ['uid0', 'uid1'];
const mapperB = ['uid3', 'uid4'];

const range = 4;

const result = Object.fromEntries(mapperA.map((A) => 
  [
    A, 
    Object.fromEntries(mapperB.map((B) => [
      B,
      Array.from({ length: range }, (_, i) => i)
    ]))
  ])
);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks friend am new with lodas lib, this help a lot